# El fichero de configuración del servidor (WILDFLY) no existe. ECLIPSE

Tags: eclipse, servidor, wildfly

Estoy tratando de iniciar el servidor Wildfly en Eclipse(STS) y me da error. Ya lo he eliminado y creado uno nuevo 4 veces: The server's configuration file does not exist: C:\Company\IDE\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml

Comment: Hola,¿podrías agregar una captura de la configuración de tú runtime environment?, de modo a verificar que esté todo correcto.

Comment: deberías de incluir el error que te da y la configuración del standalone.xml para poder ayudarte.